# Laravel - 405 Method not allowed then calling route from ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to call a route from my AJAX function but I keep getting this error:

> POST http://localhost:8000/event/updateEventPrivacy 405 (Method Not Allowed)

I can't seem to find out why. if I change the ajax method to "GET" instead of "POST", I get a different error:

> GET http://localhost:8000/updateEventPrivacy?is_checked=true&event_id=103 404 (Not Found)

which makes me wonder if I wrote some link wrong and it isn't reaching the function I want.

Here is the code, if there are any other functions that you need to fully understand problem, please let me know!

**web.php**

```
Route::post('updateEventPrivacy', 'EventController@updatePrivacy')->name('updateEventPrivacy');
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn-container" id="smth-new">
    <label class="switch btn-color-mode-switch">
        <input type="checkbox" name="color_mode" id="color_mode" value="1" onchange="updatePrivacy('#color_mode', <?php echo $event->id ?>)">
        <label for="color_mode" data-on="Private" data-off="Public" class="btn-color-mode-switch-inner"></label>
    </label>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
function updatePrivacy(ele, event_id) {
  var is_checked = $(ele).prop("checked");
  console.log("Is checked: " + is_checked);
  console.log("Event id: " + event_id);

  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/event/updateEventPrivacy",
    data: { is_checked: is_checked , event_id: event_id },
    success: function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      //changeWriting(response);
    }
  })
}
```

**EventController.php**

```
public function updatePrivacy(Request $request) {
      $input = $request->all();
      return 'update privacy working';
}
```

Comment: is the route `/event/updateEventPrivacy` or `/updateEventPrivacy`?

Comment: @ericmp the url in ajax is "/event/updateEventPrivacy", the name of the route is "updateEventPrivacy"

Comment: so u r doing a request to POST `/event/updateEventPrivacy` but u expect to listen to it registering a route that listens to  POST `/updateEventPrivacy`? or im misunderstanding u?

Comment: @ericmp I used to have the ajax url as `/updateEventPrivacy` but when I did, I had a 404 Error (Not Found) so I assumed the url had to be with `\event` before

Comment: did u try to do POST `/updateEventPrivacy` in ajax and then listen to POST `/updateEventPrivacy` in web.php? if so, what u got?

Comment: I decided to do it another way, by putting the script inside a `.blade` file and using `url: " {{ route('updateEventPrivacy') }} ",` inside ajax